# What is this game involving white disks, fish, and wavy pieces?

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm wondering if someone might be able to help me out with an odd request. Living in Ireland, someone approached me to identify a game. They found games pieces in a very old wooden box (100 years or so old). There's three types of pieces, each made of a white stone (possibly marble):

- Very thin circular white disks, maybe an inch and a half in diameter. Maybe 20 or 30 of these.
- White fish pieces, maybe 5 to 10 of these.
- What I think are river pieces (wavy lines), 5 to 10 of these too

There were no instructions for play or title or anything. I'm not sure if it was a published game or just a cobbled together family game that was ever in any way well known.

So the pieces are made of something that almost looks like marble,could be some form of white stone. I dont have a photo but will try to get one. The pieces dont look that old, but i think the box kept them in good condition

Does anyone have any idea as to what this could be?

Comment: What were the pieces made of? Wood?

Comment: Are you able to post pictures? Those are a lot of help in identifying games.

Comment: Is there a board or just pieces?

Comment: I remember my Grandparents having a game like this when I was young.   The pieces were cardboard, not stone.  It was a sort of fishing game of chance.  You "fished" for a piece and got a fish, nothing or another turn.  I don't remember any name for it.

Answer (score 2):

The material, age, lack of instructions, and the fact that some of them are shaped like fish, suggest that these are 19th-century gambling chips.

I am guessing based on the fact that some of them are in the form of fish, which was historically a common design for a gaming chip.

For example, see [here](https://tccunha.ca/products/reproduction-18th-century-bone-game-pieces-fish-shaped-gambling-chips) for a reproduction of such chips.

Perhaps you could see if there is anything similar to your pieces on [antiquegamblingchips.com](https://www.antiquegamblingchips.com/distinguish_iv_bon_cel.htm)?

Answer (score -1):

Brandubh could be a good possibility.  It's a variant of Tafl games.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafl_games